# Applescript with optional administrator privileges

Tags: applescript

I need to run a script as part of an application first-run step, to remove some legacy components from a previous version. Typically these components are installed in either $HOME/Library or /Library, and the script can simply move them to the trash.

The problem is, in the case where the user is *not* an administrator, and the components are in the global /Library, the script needs to authenticate as an administrator, or it will fail. My current script uses AppleScript, but to my surprise, I can't find a way to become an admin user in the middle of a script.

There's the 'do shell script 'foo' with administrator privileges' command, but it *always* authenticates, and it's easier to express the steps I want in AppleScript than shell, though not impossible.

At the moment I'm faced with trying to move the files in AppleScript, catching a failure of the move, and then using an authenticating shell-script to move the files using 'mv'. This seems very cumbersome, so what can I do to make things neater?

Answer (score 2):

I'd write it to use "do shell script". First I'd try it without admin privileges—if that returns an error, I'd try it with admin privileges. That way the user isn't prompted for admin credentials if they are not needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use the sudo prefix for the command, which has a 1 minute re-authentication  after you last used it.  So, for example, mv /something /something would be sudo mv /something /something